# How to update application home screen android

Tags: android

I want to create a home screen for my Android App,
were a certain area is allocated to auto updates on a certain topic.
Let's say each 30 seconds.

So for instance: The user must open the app, then on the home screen or
front page, the user must see the latest scores of different soccer games 
of a specific League. With the League being viewed changes each 30secs.

I dont really know how or what to search for on google. 
I'm relatively new to android

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a `AlarmManager` that calls a `Service` that refreshes the information every 30 secs. Than use a `BroadcastReciever` to update the UI with the new information.